# generate jbehave stories dynamically

Tags: jbehave

We are planing to generate JBehave stories dynamically by entering the when then commands (?) in a simple web form. I am not sure, if I like that idea. 
I mean, I could programatically save the .story file before starting the test and point to this file in an overwritten StoryPathResolver.resolve method. 
But, do you think that this would make a lot sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your planned feature, but based on my assumptions *), I say: no, it does not make sense for the following reasons.

My assumption on this here is that you want to perform (test) the system on-the-fly and/or you don't know how beforehand what should be tested.
But either way, whatever is typed in wont be reproducible for later regression tests nor any other typical benefit that comes with automated tests would apply, first and foremost: speed.

Instead of implementing such a framework that would present you the options available at each step as well as the stop-and-go system that would be needed, it would be way better to optimize the path of writing the .story files and inject them into a running system. This way the writer still can take any time to specify the examples as well as having them reproducible from the start.

*) Should I be wrong, please rephrase your question. There are a few other questions in your first post that I could deduct.